# storing subtypes in data structure without losing access to subtype methods

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, polymorphism

I am writing a simulation in which various agents interact with and influence each other, the code is currently structured such that all concrete classes inherit from one or more classes that define what behaviour is available to each agent instance (such as a "trader" or "talker" class) these behaviour classes also virtually inherit from an agent base class that defines behaviour and data common to all agents. this is a simple mockup of the final system

```
class agent {
    protected:
        int health;
        int mood;
        string name;
        vector<string> memories;
    public:
        agent(string name) {
            this->name = name;
            health = 20;
            mood = 0;
        }

        string getName() {
            return name;
        }

        void makeMemory(string memory) {
            memories.push_back(memory);
        }

        void takeDamage(int damage) {
            health -= damage;
        }

        void affectMood(int effect) {
            mood += effect;
        }
        
};

class fighter : public virtual agent {
    protected:
        int damage;
    public:
        virtual void attack(fighter* other) = 0;
};

class talker : public virtual agent {
    public:
        virtual void talk(talker* other) = 0;
};

struct item {
    string name;
    int value;
};

class trader : public virtual agent {  
    protected: 
        int money;
        map<string, item> inventory;
    public:
        bool spendMoney(int spend) {
            if(money - spend > 0) {
                money -= spend;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        void reciveMoney(int income) {
            money += income;
        }

        void reciveItem(item item) {
            inventory[item.name] = item;
        }

        void dropItem(string itemName) {
            inventory.erase(itemName);
        }

        const map<string, item>& viewInventory() {
            return inventory;
        }

        virtual void trade(trader* other) = 0;
};

class FightAgent: public fighter {
    public:
        FightAgent(int damage, string name) : agent(name) {
            this->damage = damage;
        }

        void attack(fighter* other) {
            cout << name + " is fighting " + other->getName() << endl;
            other->takeDamage(damage);
        }
};

class TalkAgent: public talker {
    public:
        TalkAgent(string name) : agent(name) {};

        void talk(talker* other) {
            string memory =  this->name + " talked with " + other->getName();
            cout << memory << endl;
            this->makeMemory(memory);
            other->makeMemory(memory);
        }

};

class TalkTradeAgent: public talker, public trader {
    public:
        TalkTradeAgent(string name) : agent(name) {
            money = 100;
        }

        void trade(trader* other) {
            cout << name + " is trading with " + other->getName();
            for(pair<string, item> x : other->viewInventory()) {
                if(this->spendMoney(x.second.value)) {
                    other->reciveMoney(x.second.value);
                    other->dropItem(x.second.name);
                    this->reciveItem(x.second);
                    cout << " trade succesful";
                    break;
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        void talk(talker* other) {
            string memory =  this->name + " talked with " + other->getName();
            cout << memory << endl;
            this->makeMemory(memory);
            other->makeMemory(memory);
        } 
};
```

I am struggling to build a data structure that would let me store all my final agent instances in a way that would allow me to access all the behaviour they implement

my initial solution was to use a `vector<agent*>` and compose the base agent class with a struct that defined what behaviour they implemented, and on interaction between two agents use `dynamic_cast` to downcast to the relevant direct agent subclass. This however means that I need to update the behaviour struct every time I add a new agent behaviour subclass, and requires dynamic casting which is slow. I also attempted to implement a structure that could accept any instance of a subclass of agent, and would decompose it into pointers to its behaviour parent classes, storing them in a vector of each behaviour class, however I got stuck with implementing the templates and such asked here.

Comment: Unrelated tactical note: If ownership of the `agent` becomes involved, prefer `vector<std::unique_ptr<agent>>` to `vector<agent*>`. Let the smart pointer do the heavy lifting and disposal.

Comment: @user4581301 I do intend to use smart pointers when I solve my problem and integrate with the rest of my system

Comment: Unrelated tactical note: All class members are initialized before entering the body of the constructor, so take advantage of the member initializer list where possible. Eg: write `agent(string name), name(name), health(20), mood(0) {}` instead of `agent(string name) { this->name = name; health = 20; mood = 0; }`. `name` is initialized to the correct value rather that default initialized and then assigned.

Comment: A simple way to do this is to expand the `agent` interface to include virtual do-nothing versions of all of the abilities, but this often doesn't necessarily scale well if you have a lot of different agent types or plan to add more in the future. There's a design pattern that handles this, but I can't remember the name.

Comment: First thing first, if you are inheriting from a class that does not have virtual functions, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rule of thumb. If you find yourself writing

```
void do_thing(Base* x)
{
   if (auto a = dynamic_cast<A*>(x)) a->do_a_thing();
   else if (auto b = dynamic_cast<B*>(x)) b->do_b_thing();
   ...
}
```

then `do_thing` should be a virtual function in `Base` instead.

Now this doesn't work that well (or at all) when you have *two* `Base`-derived objects and the action you need to take depends on both types. There is actually no good solution to this problem.

One solution that does work is *double dispatch*, which is a particular case of the more general *visitor pattern*. In double dispatch, each class acts as both the visitor and the visitee, while in the visitor pattern these roles are separate. We will not discuss the more general variant here.

The drawback is that you introduce a cyclic dependency between your base class and all the children. ׁHere's how one does it:

```
class DerivedA;
class DerivedB;

class Base
{
   public:     virtual void interact(Base*) = 0;
   // Here the cyclic dependency comes
   protected:  virtual void do_interact(DerivedA*) {} 
               virtual void do_interact(DerivedB*) {} 
};

class DerivedA: public virtual Base
{
   void interact(Base* base) override { base->interact(this); }
   void do_interact(DerivedA* other) override
      { /* A-A-specific interaction */ }
   // A-B interaction is a no-op
};

class DerivedB: public virtual Base
{
   void interact(Base* base) override { base->interact(this); }
   void do_interact(DerivedB* other) override
      { /* B-B-specific interaction */ }
   // A-B interaction is a no-op
};
```

If you have multiple inheritance, and each base class interacts independently, you only change this a little:

```
class DerivedAB : public DerivedA, public DerivedB
{
    void interact(Base* base) override 
      { 
         DerivedA::interact(base);
         DerivedB::interact(base);
      }
};
```

There is an *acyclic visitor* variation. It does away with the cyclic dependency for the price of using `dynamic_cast`, but it does so in a more controlled manner that doesn't necessarily require you to revisit everything when you add a new subclass. Don't worry about it being slow until you measure your performance and find it to be a bottleneck (chances of that happening are pretty much zero). You can find more info about it [here](https://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/OOT/Design-Principles/acv.pdf).

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, multiple inheritance is one feature that differentiates this question from many almost-duplicates, so I think it merits a dedicated answer.